# php mysql insert into table from text file with fixed width

Tags: php, mysql, file, insert, fixed

I'm trying to write a cron job that would run a php script which would insert data from flat (text) file with fixed columns.

My file 'data.txt' looks something like that:

```
first_column                   second_column        third_column
```

Eg. first column has width of 30 characters + 1 space for separation from next column, second 20 characters + 1 space for separation, third 15 (including whitespaces). My table 'TEST' has 3 columns: first, second and third.

Question is, how to first trim column data and then insert each row into the table?

```
<?php
// initial database stuff
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'database';
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");
$file = file('/home/user/files/data.txt'); # read file into array
$count = count($file);
if($count > 0) # file is not empty
{
    $query = "INSERT into TEST(first,second,third) values";
    $i = 1;
    foreach($file as $row)
    {
        $query .= "('TRIM(SUBSTR($row,1,30))','TRIM(SUBSTR($row,32,20))','TRIM(SUBSTR($row,34,49))')";
        $query .= $i < $count ? ',':'';
        $i++;
    }
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe trim them in PHP first before putting them into Query?

Comment: If I were you, I'd do all the bad work with PHP, rather than MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I ended up using PDO as suggested.
It works fine with strings with commas in the middle, and it skips empty rows.

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbtype = 'sqlite';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user_for_db';
$dbpass = 'pass_for_db';
$dbname = 'name_of_db';

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass);  //charset optional

// open data file
$handle = fopen('/home/user/data/file.txt', 'r');
if ($handle) 
    {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false)
        {
        // new data
        $first      =trim(substr($buffer,0,8));
        $second     =trim(substr($buffer,9,10));
        $third      =trim(substr($buffer,20,6));
        $fourth     =trim(substr($buffer,27,100));
        $fifth      =str_replace(" , ", ", ", trim(substr($buffer,128,113)));
        $sixth      =trim(substr($buffer,240,30));

        // query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table(column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5,column_6) VALUES (:first,:second,:third,:fourth,:fifth,:sixth)";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(  ':first'    =>$first,
                            ':second'   =>$second,
                            ':third'    =>$third,
                            ':fourth'   =>$fourth,
                            ':fifth'    =>$fifth,
                            ':sixth'    =>$sixth    ));
        }

        if (!feof($handle))
        {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
        }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "File data successfully imported to database!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is how it might look like:

```
<?php
// initial database stuff
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'database';
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");
$file = file('/home/user/files/data.txt'); # read file into array
$count = count($file);
// Edited to add loop back in... Silly me.
if($count > 0) # file is not empty

{
    foreach ($file as $row){
        $first=trim(substr($row,0,30));
        $second=trim(substr($row,31,20));
        $third=trim(substr($row,33,49));

        $query = "INSERT into TEST(first,second,third) values".
                 "($first,$second,$third)";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
?>
```

Consider using PDO and prepared statement, to make it even cleaner ( and safer ).

Comment: Opps it would not. Fixed now.

Comment: In strings I'm trying to insert there are some commas as well. I noticed I get an error wherever comma is present in a column. Otherwise it works. Can we insert with commas and without errors?
And file has also empty rows. How can we skip those? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will definitely want to use PDO to ensure your insert escapes these trouble characters. Please look up for PDO insert, as it is a bit out of this topic and is bit of read. As for empty rows, simply add an if check to makesure you get strings before executing the sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
// initial database stuff
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'database';
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");
$file = file('/home/user/files/data.txt'); # read file into array
$count = count($file);
if($count > 0) # file is not empty
{
foreach($file as $key => $row)
{
    if( $key == 0 ){
        $col_1 = str_replace( " ", "" , trim(substr($row,1,30));
        $col_2 = str_replace( " ", "" , trim(substr($row,32,20));
        $col_3 = str_replace( " ", "" , trim(substr($row,34,49));
        $query = "INSERT into TEST(col_1,col_2,col_3) values";
    }
    else {
       $query .= "'TRIM(SUBSTR($row,1,30))','TRIM(SUBSTR($row,32,20))','TRIM(SUBSTR($row,34,49))')";
       $query .= $key < $count ? ',':'';
    }
}
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
?>
```